# Access any page with URL in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, routes

My app provides a Portfolio sharing feature by providing a unique link for the user. User1 can share this link to User2 and User2 can easily access User1's Portfolio (for read only).

I want that the user2 can access this page directly <Route path="/user/:userId" element={} />
by typing the url in the browser. But this is not happening and the page responds "Not found"

```
function App() {
  
  return (
     
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div className='mainDiv'>
        <Header />        
        <Routes>

        <Route path='/' element={<Homepage/>} exact/>
        <Route path='/coins/:id' element={<CoinPage/>}/> 
        <Route path='/portfolio/:user' element={<Portfolio/>} />
        <Route path="/user/:userId" element={<PublicPort/>} />
        </Routes>
    </div>
    <Alert/>
    </BrowserRouter>

    
   
  );
}

export default App;
```